# Appending a list of dictionaries within a matrix

Tags: python

I am writing a script to parse baseball game data. In my script, I am working with a matrix where the value of each element is a dictionary. For example:

```
{'Date':gameDate},{'Home Team':homeTeam},{'Away Team':awayTeam}
```

So the parser creates a list of games. If I want to print games where the White Sox are the away team, I write the following:

```
for event in gameMatrix:
    if event['Away Team'] == "Chicago White Sox":
        print event.items()
```

The output is, for example:

```
[('Date', '2013-05-17 02:05'), ('Away Team', 'Chicago White Sox'), ('Home Team', 'LAA Angels')]
```

But lets say I want to add another dictionary to specific types of games, again lets use White Sox games as an example: (in pseudo code)

```
for event in gameMatrix:
    if event['Away Team'] == "Chicago White Sox":
        append {'New Value': "New value"}
        print event.items()
```

So the expected output would be

```
{'Date':gameDate},{'Home Team':homeTeam},{'Away Team':awayTeam}{'New Value':"New Value"}
```

But everything I've tried ends up giving me errors of some sort (i.e. 'dict' object has no attribute 'append', list indices must be integers, keyerror, etc.)

So, how can I append a new dictionary to a specific row of the gameMatrix?

Comment: Why do you have (a list of) separate dictionaries and not one dictionary with multiple keys?

Comment: @JonClements I think you are mis-interpreting his mis-described structures?

Comment: @JonClements Clements I'm inserting them into a MySQL database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood something,

```
for event in gameMatrix:
    if event['Away Team'] == "Chicago White Sox":
       event['new key'] = 'New value'
       print event.items()
```